# How do I force make to clean and recompile after changes to Makefile itself?

Tags: makefile

I sometimes change the Makefile but that change itself does not cause make to recompile my sources.

I tried something like this (EXEC is my executable, clean is the usual deletion of source and intermediate compilation output)

```
$(EXEC): Makefile
         make clean
         make
```

but this generates an infinite loop... any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have can't work because after `make clean` the `$(EXEC)` file won't exist, so it's always out of date, so it's always rebuilt, and the rebuild will run `clean` then re-exec itself, so again it will be out of date, so again make will run `clean` then re-exec itself, etc.

To do what you want you need to list the makefile as a prerequisite of *all* of the targets.  Then you don't need to run `clean` or re-run `make`, because all the targets will be out of date when the makefile changes, just as they'd be out of date if the source file changed.  So, as an example, add `Makefile` as a prerequisite to your object file targets:

```
%.o : %.c Makefile
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

Without knowing anything about the rest of your makefile we can't give more specific advice than that.

Comment: This works. Out of curiosity, if I have something like this, how do I prevent the $+ to add the Makefile to the compile command?
$(EXEC): $(subst .f90,.o,$(SOURCES) $(DEPENDENCIES))
         $(COMPILE) -o $@ $+

Comment: First, you probably don't really  need to list `Makefile` as a prerequisite of your executable: if it's a prerequisite of all your object files then they'll be rebuilt when `Makefile` changes and that will always cause your executable to be rebuilt anyway.  But, if you want to do this you can use `$(filter-out Makefile,$+)`

Comment: If you can assume you have GNU make 4.3, then you can take advantage of the `.EXTRA_PREREQS` feature; see https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Variables.html